# Oyster card vs Travelcard from Woking for a weekend

Tags: trains, london, price

I'm planning on travelling into London from Woking this weekend, with a number of specific places I'm going to visit. It'll be into London (zone 1) on Friday evening, then on to zone 3, and then on Saturday it'll be zones 1, 2 and 3, and then return to Woking on Saturday evening.

My ticket options appear to be:

- Super Off-peak Travelcard on Friday (£17.50) and another on Saturday (£17.50)
- Singles between Woking and Surbiton<sup>1</sup> (2 @ £6.30) plus Oyster card
- Singles between Woking and Clapham Junction (2 @ £8.30) plus Oyster card

I can find how much the Oyster card will cost to get (deposit, register, initial credit)<sup>2</sup>, but what I can't find is how much the Oyster card will actually "cost" for the journeys inside London, either from Waterloo to my zone 3 destination or from there back to either Clapham Junction or Surbiton.

---

<sup>1</sup> Surbiton is the furthest out that Oyster will cover.

<sup>2</sup> [Oyster & Travel Cards](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/27702/oyster-travel-cards) is the best hit I've found on here, but other sites also have the basic information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The costs can be computed based on [this PDF table](https://www.tfl.gov.uk/cdn/static/cms/documents/tube-dlr-lo-adult-fares-jan-2014.pdf) ([permanent link in case of update](https://www.tfl.gov.uk/fares-and-payments/fares)) or using the [Single Fare Finder](http://www.tfl.gov.uk/fares-and-payments/fares/single-fare-finder).

With an Oyster card, a journey from Waterloo to Clapham Junction (zone 2) costs £2.20. From Waterloo to zone 3, you would pay £2.70 (all off-peak fares). If you plan several journeys within zone 1-3 on Saturday, you would pay £7.70 in total. For Surbiton, the Fare Finder and the table don't seem to agree, so I am not sure how much it would actually cost. In any case, the cheapest option seems to be the third one (not taking the deposit for the Oyster card into account).

Comment: Perfect though this answer would otherwise have been, it was foiled because Woking station (outside the Oyster area) cannot sell Oyster cards, so I had to go into Waterloo (two singles @ £10.70) and then buy one (£10) there.

Comment: @ClickRick You'd have had to get off the train and probably gone through the barriers anyway at the point where you switched from the tickets to Oyster so you could have bought the Oyster at that point.

Comment: @Ganesh This answer recommended the third option from my question (i.e. do the change at Clapham). There is no need to get out at Clapham when travelling from Woking to Waterloo (not all trains even stop there), so no barriers to go through, and thus no opportunity to buy an Oyster card there. If I could have bought my Oyster card at Woking then Relaxed's answer would have been perfect, but as it was I was forced to go in to Waterloo and buy it there, as I said.

Comment: @ClickRick Even if you had an Oyster card already, you have to explicitly touch in with it to start using it. You can't just start a Pay-As-You-Go Oyster journey without doing that, so you can't use a Single from Woking to Clapham Junction and Oyster from Clapham Junction to Waterloo without getting a train that stops at Clapham Junction and getting off there.